# Rails is Looking for a Partial in the Wrong Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, partials

I have a polymorphic `Review` model. The namespaced model `User::Library::Publication` is reviewable. The reviews are created properly, but when I try to display them through a partial, Rails looks up the wrong directory.

In my view:

```
<%= render @review %>
```

I get this error:

```
Missing partial user/library/reviews/review with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}
```

Rails is apparently looking for the review partial within the namespace's directory `views/user/library` instead of the `/views/reviews`. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Just so we understand your question, where did you expect it to look?

Comment: In `/views/reviews/_review.html.erb`.

Comment: Is your controller namespaced as well?

Comment: It is: `User::Library::PublicationsController`

Comment: Try `<%= render 'review' %>`

Comment: That's why rails is looking for your partial in a namespaced directory.

Comment: @Fred I had no idea namespacing affected so much, though now it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove namespacing from the partial template path, you can set the `prefix_partial_path_with_controller_namespace` variable in your `config/application.rb`:

```
# config/application.rb
config.action_view.prefix_partial_path_with_controller_namespace = false
```

This will load partial paths as you define them (without the namespace).

You can [see the original Pull Request here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5625).

Answer (score 0):

If you use name spaces you have to create folders/sub folders so Rails is not looking at the wrong place.

If you want to force the partial path just use:

```
render :partial => "review"
```

And create rename the `review.html.erb` file to `_review.html.erb`

Comment: Simply rendering `:partial => "review"` doesn't seem to do the trick. I'm only having success when I'm super specific: `render :partial => "/reviews/review", :locals => {:review => @review}`

Comment: Having not so much of information I could only give a direction, but if you estimate that my answer isn't correct...